# Moving items from personal calendar to a team calendar where invite is received and auto-accepted?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to automatically add the Zoom meetings we receive from Salesforce to our team calendar.

Thanks to https://www.slipstick.com/developer/copy-new-appointments-to-another-calendar-using-vba/ I was able to get very close. The script works if I create the appointment as a test, but not when the appointment is sent to me and I accept the invite. (My Outlook settings are configured to automatically accept all invitations.)

When I debug, it highlights `.Start = Item.Start` in `curCal_ItemAdd`:

```
Dim WithEvents curCal As Items
Dim newCalFolder As Outlook.Folder

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' calendar to watch for new items
    Set curCal = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
    ' calendar moving copy to
    Set objOwner = NS.CreateRecipient("Team Calendar")
    objOwner.Resolve

     If objOwner.Resolved Then
        'MsgBox objOwner.Name
        Set newCalFolder = NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)
    End If
    Set NS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub curCal_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim moveCal As AppointmentItem

' On Error Resume Next

' copy only Zoom Meetings
' remove to make a copy of all items
If Item.Subject Like "Zoom Meeting Invitation*" Then
    Set cAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With cAppt
        .Subject = Mid(Item.Subject, 28)

        .Start = Item.Start    ' ** highlighted text 

        .Duration = Item.Duration
        .Location = Item.Location
        .Body = Item.Body
    End With

' set the category after it's moved to force EAS to sync changes
Set moveCal = cAppt.Move(newCalFolder)
moveCal.Categories = "Webex"
moveCal.Save

End If
End Sub

Public Function GetDATETIME() As String
    GetDATETIME = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
End Function

Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function

GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Once I have clicked reset in the VBA editor, if I open the invite and click "accept invitation" again it works as it is supposed to. The first time it runs it isn't picking up the invitation's start time.

I tried to introduce a time delay, but none of the attempts at doing so made any difference. For all I know I put the time delay in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: Changed the code here

```
If Item.Subject like "Zoom Invitation Meeting*" and Item.BusyStatus = olBusy Then
```

This solved the issue by attempting to add the appointment to the new calendar after the appointment was accepted.

I noticed when I turned off Auto-accept that it generated 2 meetings, one before I accepted the invitation and one after. By preventing appointments from being copied until after being accepted I solved my problem. Guess I shouldn't have removed that piece of the code from the initial article. Whoops.